# why bother using (char **endptr) instead of (char ch) or (char *chptr) in the function strtod()

Tags: c, string, pointers

`double strtod(const char *str, char **endptr);`

The argument **endptr** is a pointer to a pointer. The address of the character that stopped the scan is stored in the pointer that endptr points to.

why bother using (char **endptr) instead of (char ch) or (char *chptr) in the function strtod().

Thanks.

Comment: Is 'for consistency with the other `strtoX()` functions' a good enough reason?  The functions `strtol()`, `strtoll()`, `strtoul()`, `strtoull()`, `strtoimax()`, `strtoumax()`, `strtof()`, and `strtold()` all take a `char **endptr`.  (Of course the answer's NO — why do they take the `char **` argument too.  For that, see Daniel Fischer's answer.)  An alternative design might have used an `int *endoffset` argument (for some type of integer) in place of `char **endptr`; that would work equivalently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why bother using `(char **endptr)` instead of `(char ch)` or `(char *chptr)` in the function `strtod()`

Because that argument is meant to give information to the caller. So it must modify memory that the caller controls, and that is typically and most easily done by passing the address of a variable in the caller.

One could have an argument of type `char*` that points to a single `char` variable in the caller, but that would not allow an easy check of whether the result should be accepted (e.g. if trailing whitespace is to be ignored) or if further processing of the remainder of the input string is desired.

Having the type `char**` allows using `strtoX` in parsers quite comfortably, they leave a pointer to the remainder of the string after they have consumed their part.

If the type were `char*`, and only the `char` after the part `strtoX` consumed were saved, it would require locating the point of further parsing by essentially re-parsing the number.

Comment: The real question is why is a pointer to a `char` instead of a pointer to `const char` :-D

Answer (score 2):

Because with a `char *` you would only have information about the value of the character that stopped the scan, whereas with a `char **` you have information about the location (memory address) of the character, which allows you to further process the remainder of the string.

As the example of [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtod/) shows, you can do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char szOrbits[] = "365.24 29.53";
  char *pEnd;
  double d1, d2;

  d1 = strtod(szOrbits, &pEnd);
  d2 = strtod(pEnd, NULL);
  printf("The moon completes %.2f orbits per Earth year.\n", d1 / d2);

  return (0);
}
```